# Unsual behaviour on onClick of Button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, onclicklistener

In my app on registering user on Click of button first Iam validating form that no fields should be empty and then Iam calling 2 functions after this one is to get Lat Long from address and other is email authentication which is after success pushing data to DB.

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                   registerFormValidation();

               /* getLocationFromAddress(userAddress);
                    getEmailAuth(); */
```

I have commented the both function because when I click on register button its directly give me exception that email and password is empty for createuserwithemailpassword without validating the form.Then I paste these two function in registerFormValidation() like this.But It won't go in the else statement and not call those 2 function, though its validating form properly but after validation it wont go in else statement for those 2 functions

```
private void registerFormValidation() {

        username = userName.getText().toString();
        userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        birthDate = dob.getText().toString();
        userAddress = address.getText().toString();
        userPassword = password.getText().toString();
        rePassword = confirmPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.usernameRequired);
            userName.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailRequired);
            email.requestFocus();
        } else if (!isValidEmail(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailFormat);
            email.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(birthDate)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.bithDateRequired);
            dob.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userAddress)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.addressRequired);
            address.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.passwordRequired);
            password.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.repassword);
            confirmPassword.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(gender)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.gender);

        } else if (!userPassword.equals(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.matchPassword);
            password.requestFocus();

        }  else  {
            getLocationFromAddress(userAddress);
            getEmailAuth();
        }
```

This is my whole class

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userName, email, phoneNum, dob,  password, confirmPassword, address;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    Button registerButton, pickAddress;
    TextView alreadyHaveAccount, diseasesType;
    LinearLayout donarLayout;
    RelativeLayout rootView;
    private String mobileNum, username, userEmail, birthDate, userAddress, userPassword, rePassword,gender,  userID;
    ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
    ImageView calendar, calendar1;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    LatLng p1 = null;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        viewDecleration();
        clickFunctionalitites();

    }

    private void viewDecleration() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.profiles);

        progressDialog = HelperClass.showProgressDialog(this, Constants.progressMsg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.parentView);

        userName = findViewById(R.id.etuserName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        phoneNum = findViewById(R.id.etPhoenNum);
        dob = findViewById(R.id.etDob);
        lasTimeDonated = findViewById(R.id.etLastTimeDonated);
        address = findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        height = findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        weight = findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        confirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.etConfirm);

        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.sexGroup);

        bloodDonater = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_donar);
        checkHepatitis = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_hepatitis);
        checkBp = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_bp);
        checkAids = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_aids);
        checkCancer = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_cancer);
        checkAllergy = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_allergy);
        checkSugar = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_sugar);
        checkTatto = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tatto);

        alreadyHaveAccount = findViewById(R.id.loginFromSignup);

        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        pickAddress = findViewById(R.id.pickAddress);

        donarLayout = findViewById(R.id.donateBlodLayout);

        calendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendar1 = findViewById(R.id.calendar1);

    }

    private void registerFormValidation() {

        username = userName.getText().toString();
        userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        birthDate = dob.getText().toString();
        userAddress = address.getText().toString();
        userPassword = password.getText().toString();
        rePassword = confirmPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.usernameRequired);
            userName.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailRequired);
            email.requestFocus();
        } else if (!isValidEmail(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailFormat);
            email.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(birthDate)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.bithDateRequired);
            dob.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userAddress)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.addressRequired);
            address.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.passwordRequired);
            password.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.repassword);
            confirmPassword.requestFocus();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(gender)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.gender);

        } else if (!userPassword.equals(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.matchPassword);
            password.requestFocus();

        } else {
             getLocationFromAddress(userAddress);
            getEmailAuth();
        }

    }


    private void donarLayoutCheck() {

        if (bloodDonater.isChecked()) {
            donarCheck = "yes";
            donarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            donarCheck = "no";
            donarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private void clickFunctionalitites() {

        bloodDonater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (bloodDonater.isChecked()) {
                    donarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    donarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });


        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                progressDialog.show();
                        registerFormValidation();
getLocationFromAddress(userAddress);
               getEmailAuth();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getEmailAuth() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "emai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String error;
                            try {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                throw task.getException();
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
//                               password.setError(getString(Constants.error_weak_password));
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                error = e.getMessage();
                                HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, error);
                                password.requestFocus();
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                error = e.getMessage();
                                HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, error);
                                email.requestFocus();
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                error = e.getMessage();
                                HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, error);
                                email.requestFocus();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                error = e.getMessage();
                                HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, error);
                            }


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Auth success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            }
                            pushData();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void pushData() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.profiles).child(userID);
        HashMap userMap = new HashMap();

        userMap.put("name", username);
        userMap.put("email", userEmail);

        userMap.put("dob", birthDate);
        userMap.put("last_blood_donation", lastDonation);
        userMap.put("donar", donarCheck);
        userMap.put("height", userHeight);
        userMap.put("weight", userWeight);
        userMap.put("address", userAddress);
/*        userMap.put("latitude", userLat);
        userMap.put("longitude", userLong);*/
//        userMap.put("password", userPassword);
        userMap.put("gender", gender);
        userMap.put("diseases", final_checkBox_selection);

        databaseReference.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Task successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }


    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null)
            return false;

        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }

    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "emai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> address;

        try {
            // May throw an IOException
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
            if (address == null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                return null;
            }
            try {
                Address location = address.get(0);
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                userLat = String.valueOf(latitude);
                userLong = String.valueOf(longitude);
                System.out.println("add" + latitude + " , " + longitude);

                p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Address not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return p1;
    }
}
```

Iam repeating my question that if I place three function in on Register click button it directly give me exception without calling registerFormValidation and if I only call register formvalidation function on register click button it dont go in else statement and dont call the other two func.
Its a bit weird but don't know why its happening

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: please add your stack traces so we can see what error you get

Comment: Iam not getting any crash or any error in my logcat.It not crashing the app or giving me error

Comment: If exception occur than logcat showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not entering `else if (!isValidEmail(userEmail))` , then it means that the if statements before it are returning false and it is directly going into the last else statement. Therefore instead of doing if..else if .., you need to use only if to check every case:

```
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.usernameRequired);
            userName.requestFocus();
        } 
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailRequired);
            email.requestFocus();
        } 
   if (!isValidEmail(userEmail)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.emailFormat);
            email.requestFocus();

        } 
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(birthDate)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.bithDateRequired);
            dob.requestFocus();

        } 
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userAddress)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.addressRequired);
            address.requestFocus();

        } 
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.passwordRequired);
            password.requestFocus();

        } 
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.repassword);
            confirmPassword.requestFocus();
        } 
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(gender)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.gender);

        } 
    if (!userPassword.equals(rePassword)) {
            HelperClass.showSnakbarMsg(rootView, Constants.matchPassword);
            password.requestFocus();

        }  else  {
            getLocationFromAddress(userAddress);
            getEmailAuth();
        }
```

Comment: yes I have found the issue we can do it your way but still it leave a flaw according to my requirements so I added an extra condition for this. Thanku though for your time.